# Correct way to dynamically load modules with static typing in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, module

I am using TypeScript and WebPack.

There is one module which I need to be loaded dynamically.
Current solution is:

```
declare function require(module: string): any;

const m = require("./something");
m.f();
```

But this way I loose my static typing compared to:

```
import {f} from "./something";
```

Is there a way to type dynamically loaded module with my module type ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to use

```
    import * as something from './something'
    something.fn()
```

Otherwise please elaborate on your question.

There are several types of imports available in Typesscript

```
    import {something} from './something' //represents a named class or function
    something from './something' //represents a default export from a module
    import * as something from './something' // is equivalent to let method=require("something")
```

Please see full reference here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Update

> The compiler detects whether each module is used in the emitted JavaScript. If a module identifier is only ever used as part of a type annotations and never as an expression, then no require call is emitted for that module. This elision of unused references is a good performance optimization, and also allows for optional loading of those modules.

According to the docs this can be handled different by systemjs,requirejs,and node.

```
//node
If(...){let a=require('something')}
//system
If(...){require(['something'],(a))=>{...}}
```

Comment: import will add a static module. Meaning the module will be loaded right away when I import it. I want to load it delayed only when I need.

Comment: The problem is with the typing. I have module typed as 'any'.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution:

```
import * as Something from "something"; //this will give you access to type

if(..) {
  let a: typeof Something = require("something")
}
```

There is however a problem with this that if the "something" module has interfaces or types exposed, they will not be shown as a part of "typeof Something". So if someone would help with this, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I just typed require with
declare function require(s: "jquery"): JQueryStatic;

Not perfect but good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
const m = await import("./something");
```